# how to redirect a link in my website to an external link?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have provided a link from my web site in my andoird app which is:

> www.mysite.com/support

And i want this link to be redirected to:

> www.anothersite.com

i have already tried com_redirect and entered `support` as source and `http://ww.anothersite.com` but i dont get any redirects and i get 404 error.

I am running Joomla 3.x and i want to know how i can do this with URL rewrites and no external components.

Comment: I believe you have to enter the full url (`http://www.mysite.com/support`) not just `support` to get it to match.

Comment: i get tho following error when i do as u say: `Save failed with the following error: The source URL must be unique.`the problem is with the external link.internal links work ok with `com_redirect`

Comment: That error should just mean that `http://www.mysite.com/support` is already in the system. If you have been to the url, there is likely already a record for it, but you have to make sure it is published to redirect it.

Comment: Thanks but have u already tried on ur server? pls check ur solution first.yes it is enabled and there is no other support pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems not possible to do it within the Joomla backend (i tried many combination of menu items and the redirect module). 
For sure you can write your redirect directly in your .htaccess (if you are using it) like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^support/?$    http://www.anothersite.com/    [R=301,NC,L]    # Permanent Move
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^support/?$    http://www.anothersite.com    [R,NC,L]    # Temporary Move
```

More info about URL rewriting and .htaccess are here: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/